# Можно ли прочитать push уведомление на андроид

Tags: android, python, push-уведомления

Я бы хотел, чтобы приложение на питон считывало push уведомления и сохраняло их в файл.

И я не знаю как это сделать и можно ли вообще?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35114461/how-can-i-read-push-notification-from-other-apps

Comment: Спасибо. А для python аналога нет?

Comment: Не знаю. И совет: не пишите под андроид на python, это _прекрансый_ язык, но он — не для этого. Если андроид — то джава.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23219010/kivy-use-android-notifications